# For loop into array in a certain format

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, format

I've been trying to create an array from a for loop, using push which creates an array in the format ["value, value, value, value, value, value"] but I need it to create an array in the following format: [["value, value, value"],["value, value, value"]

The original array is created without a for loop like this:

```
new array (["1","2",3"],["1,2,3"],["1,2,3"],["1,2,3"]);
```

so how do I go about creating the same using a loop instead?

```
var colour = ["red","green","blue","orange"];

for (i=1; i<5; i++){

var name = $("#name"+i).val();                                      

var can = $("#candidate"+i).val();

arrayOfData = new Array([can,name,colour[i]]); 

}
```

Comment: How exactly does this transformation work? Each set of 3 elements are replaced by a list element containing them? And what exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Just push your `arrayOfData` itself to an array.

```
var array = [];
var colour = ["red","green","blue","orange"];
for (i=1; i<5; i++){
    var name = $("#name"+i).val();                                      
    var can = $("#candidate"+i).val();
    arrayOfData = [can,name,colour[i-1]]; 
    array.push(arrayOfData);
}
```

​
Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/f5J5z/4/

Comment: @NickSmith is this the result you need?  `[["1","2","red"],["1","2","3"],["1","2","3"],["1","2","orange"]);`?